# Getting error when iterating through JSON results from IBM Watson API python

Tags: python, json, loops, jinja2, ibm-watson

I am using IBM Watson's Natural Language Understanding API to get back keywords and entities from a URL. I want to iterate through the JSON response to get all the keywords and entities and have them populate in my results.html file.

I'm trying to iterate through the results in the application.py file and the results.html file which uses jinja.

The helpers.py file is returning a json.dump and sending it to my application.py file so that I can iterate through the results.

However, I'm getting the following error:

```
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

I've looked up json.dump vs json.load and strings and dictionaries to help solve this problem, but i can't get the code to work. If you need more info, please let me know. I need to get this figured out before the end of the year. Thank you in advance.

Here is the my applications.py file

```
@app.route("/URL", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def URL():
"""Analyze URL."""

 # if user reached route via POST (as by submitting a form via POST)
if request.method == "POST":

    # if nothing was entered return apology
    if not request.form.get("URL"):
        return apology("please enter a URL")
    URL = request.form.get("URL")

    # analyze URL using analyze function in helpers.py
    results = analyze(request.form.get("URL"))

    for item in results:
        keywords = item["keywords"]["text"]
        entities = item["entities"]["text"]

    return render_template("results.html", results=results, URL=URL) 

    # check if URL is valid
    if not results:
        return apology("this is not a valid URL")

else:
    return render_template("url.html")
```

Here is the helpers.py file.

```
def analyze(URL):

natural_language_understanding = NaturalLanguageUnderstandingV1(
    version='2017-02-27',
    username='MUSTGETYOURUSERNAME',
    password='MUSTGETYOURPASSWORD')

response = natural_language_understanding.analyze(
    url=URL,
    features=Features(entities=EntitiesOptions(), keywords=KeywordsOptions()))

return (json.dumps(response, indent=2))
```

Here is the results.html file using jinja:

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}

{% block title %}
Results
{% endblock %}

{% block main %}
        <h2>Powered by IBM Watson's AI to recommend your #'s and @'s 
for tweeting</h2>
        <p>{{URL}}</p>
         {% for item in results %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{ item.keywords }}</td>
                <td>{{ item.entities }}</td>
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}

        <a class="twitter-share-button" 
href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet">Tweet</a>
{% endblock %}
```

Here is what the output looks like:

```
[
  {
    "text": "Android apps",
    "relevance": 0.926516
  },
  {
    "text": "Chrome OS",
    "relevance": 0.878045
  },
  {
    "text": "Sorry Android fanboys",
    "relevance": 0.696885
  },
  {
    "text": "Android tablet",
    "relevance": 0.695471
  },
  {
    "text": "absolutely wonderful Android",
    "relevance": 0.672889
  },
  {
    "text": "Chrome OS beta",
    "relevance": 0.626619
  },
  {
    "text": "Android Police",
    "relevance": 0.592994
  },
  {
    "text": "Chrome OS devices",
    "relevance": 0.566831
  },
  {
    "text": "count Android",
    "relevance": 0.563911
  },
  {
    "text": "dominant Google OS",
    "relevance": 0.553724
  },
  {
    "text": "Chrome Unboxed",
    "relevance": 0.540076
  },
  {
    "text": "overall tablet sales",
    "relevance": 0.511826
  },
  {
    "text": "inexpensive Google rival",
    "relevance": 0.498259
  },
  {
    "text": "half incremental improvements",
    "relevance": 0.468663
  },
  {
    "text": "standard operating procedure",
    "relevance": 0.45946
  },
  {
    "text": "uncommon Chromebook form",
    "relevance": 0.456969
  },
  {
    "text": "content consumption machines",
    "relevance": 0.451775
  },
  {
    "text": "absolute best pieces",
    "relevance": 0.450763
  },
  {
    "text": "content creation ones",
    "relevance": 0.450345
  },
  {
    "text": "rich new fusion",
    "relevance": 0.446127
  },
  {
    "text": "Amazon Fire tablet",
    "relevance": 0.444685
  },
  {
    "text": "selling tablet",
    "relevance": 0.444241
  },
  {
    "text": "tablet operating",
    "relevance": 0.440434
  },
  {
    "text": "Google Pixelbook",
    "relevance": 0.440007
  },
  {
    "text": "Google store",
    "relevance": 0.439719
  },
  {
    "text": "cheap tablets",
    "relevance": 0.408395
  },
  {
    "text": "immortal highlander",
    "relevance": 0.404233
  },
  {
    "text": "disparate OSes",
    "relevance": 0.401626
  },
  {
    "text": "laptop space",
    "relevance": 0.40117
  },
  {
    "text": "detachable two-in-one",
    "relevance": 0.396257
  },
  {
    "text": "pleasant surprises",
    "relevance": 0.394027
  },
  {
    "text": "additional oomph",
    "relevance": 0.393127
  },
  {
    "text": "Samsung",
    "relevance": 0.391534
  },
  {
    "text": "flashy Chromebook",
    "relevance": 0.391359
  },
  {
    "text": "sleek Chromebook",
    "relevance": 0.390035
  },
  {
    "text": "smaller devices",
    "relevance": 0.389106
  },
  {
    "text": "operating systems",
    "relevance": 0.388958
  },
  {
    "text": "new feature",
    "relevance": 0.388395
  },
  {
    "text": "true multitasking",
    "relevance": 0.388097
  },
  {
    "text": "tablet-like device",
    "relevance": 0.387175
  },
  {
    "text": "two-in-one Chromebook",
    "relevance": 0.385518
  },
  {
    "text": "nightmare fuel",
    "relevance": 0.385284
  },
  {
    "text": "mouse-first OS—not",
    "relevance": 0.385193
  },
  {
    "text": "parallel tasks",
    "relevance": 0.381923
  },
  {
    "text": "budget device",
    "relevance": 0.380932
  },
  {
    "text": "iPad",
    "relevance": 0.35313
  },
  {
    "text": "news",
    "relevance": 0.333007
  },
  {
    "text": "strides",
    "relevance": 0.319667
  },
  {
    "text": "iOS",
    "relevance": 0.318235
  },
  {
    "text": "thanks",
    "relevance": 0.316534
  }
]

[
  {
    "type": "Company",
    "text": "Google",
    "relevance": 0.385564,
    "disambiguation": {
      "subtype": [
        "AcademicInstitution",
        "AwardPresentingOrganization",
        "OperatingSystemDeveloper",
        "ProgrammingLanguageDeveloper",
        "SoftwareDeveloper",
        "VentureFundedCompany"
      ],
      "name": "Google",
      "dbpedia_resource": "http://dbpedia.org/resource/Google"
    },
    "count": 9
  },
  {
    "type": "Company",
    "text": "Samsung",
    "relevance": 0.204475,
    "disambiguation": {
      "subtype": [],
      "name": "Samsung",
      "dbpedia_resource": "http://dbpedia.org/resource/Samsung"
    },
    "count": 4
  },
  {
    "type": "Location",
    "text": "Chromebooks",
    "relevance": 0.129986,
    "disambiguation": {
      "subtype": [
        "City"
      ]
    },
    "count": 2
  },
  {
    "type": "Company",
    "text": "Amazon",
    "relevance": 0.119948,
    "disambiguation": {
      "subtype": [],
      "name": "Amazon.com",
      "dbpedia_resource": "http://dbpedia.org/resource/Amazon.com"
    },
    "count": 2
  },
  {
    "type": "Location",
    "text": "US",
    "relevance": 0.109124,
    "disambiguation": {
      "subtype": [
        "Region",
        "AdministrativeDivision",
        "GovernmentalJurisdiction",
        "FilmEditor",
        "Country"
      ],
      "name": "United States",
      "dbpedia_resource": "http://dbpedia.org/resource/United_States"
    },
    "count": 1
  },
  {
    "type": "Company",
    "text": "Apple",
    "relevance": 0.108271,
    "disambiguation": {
      "subtype": [
        "Brand",
        "OperatingSystemDeveloper",
        "ProcessorManufacturer",
        "ProgrammingLanguageDesigner",
        "ProgrammingLanguageDeveloper",
        "ProtocolProvider",
        "SoftwareDeveloper",
        "VentureFundedCompany",
        "VideoGameDeveloper",
        "VideoGamePublisher"
      ],
      "name": "Apple Inc.",
      "dbpedia_resource": "http://dbpedia.org/resource/Apple_Inc."
    },
    "count": 1
  },
  {
    "type": "Quantity",
    "text": "$500",
    "relevance": 0.0746897,
    "count": 1
  },
  {
    "type": "Quantity",
    "text": "$50",
    "relevance": 0.0746897,
    "count": 1
  }
]
```

Comment: Which line is the error from?

Comment: File "/home/ubuntu/workspace/project/application.py", line 70, in URL
    keywords = item["keywords"]["text"]
TypeError: string indices must be integers

Comment: Either `item` is a string, or `item["keywords"]` is a string.  It would help if you included the output of `print(item)` in your question.

Comment: I included the output now.

Comment: If `item` or `item["keywords"]` are strings, then how do I need to modify my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's some confusion going on here.  You're not handling the Watson API response particularly well and it also seems you're misunderstanding the shape that this response comes back in.

Your `analyze` function handles the response from the Watson API call.  The Watson API helpfully parses the JSON response it gets back from the server into Python objects such as lists and dicts.  However, your code then calls `json.dumps` to convert that back to a string.  In this way you're undoing some of the work the Watson API has done for you.  Don't call `json.dumps` on `response`, just return `response`.

(I'm guessing you've taken this from the official IBM documentation [here](https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/natural-language-understanding/api/v1/?python#post-analyze): it has the same call to `json.dumps` but the Python code sample only has that in for demonstration purposes.)

This explains the error you are getting: `results` is therefore a string, and so when you iterate over it using `for item in results`, each `item` is a 1-character string.

However, making this change won't be enough to get your code working.  Next, we have to look at the loop where the error occurs, as there is still a problem with it:

```
    for item in results:
        keywords = item["keywords"]["text"]
        entities = item["entities"]["text"]
```

This code treats `results` as if it were a list, with each `item` in the list being a dict containing a `keywords` property and an `entities` property.  In other words, it assumes the data looks something like the following:

```
[
    {
        "keywords": { "text": "abc123", ... },
        "entities": { "text": "def456", ... },
        ...
    },
    {
        "keywords": { "text": "cba321", ... },
        "entities": { "text": "fed654", ... },
        ...
    },
    ...
]
```

However, if you take a closer look at the [the IBM documentation](https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/natural-language-understanding/api/v1/?python#post-analyze) (same page as linked to above), the response comes back in a different shape.  It looks more like this:

```
{
    "keywords": [
        { "text": "abc123", ... },
        { "text": "def456", ... }
    ],
    "entities": [
        { "text": "ghi789", ... }
    ],
    ...
}
```

In particular, `keywords` and `entities` are separate lists under the top-level object/dict, and they might not have the same length.

Instead of your loop above, you probably want something more like the following:

```
    for item in results["keywords"]:
        keyword_text = item["text"]

    for item in results["entities"]:
        entity_text = item["text"]
```

However, I'm not sure what your original loop was supposed to do: it would fetch data out of your Watson response and then do nothing with the data it fetched out.

You'll also need to modify your Jinja template to include two separate loops.  I'll leave this up to you.

Finally, you write the following code:

```
    return render_template("results.html", results=results, URL=URL) 

    # check if URL is valid
    if not results:
        return apology("this is not a valid URL")
```

It's too late to check if the URL is valid after we've already returned!  The check (`if not results`) is unreachable and will never run.   Move this check to just after the line `results = analyze(...)`.

Comment: Thank you so much!!! I was actually doing the same loop originally but changed it because I couldn't get it to work. I realize now that it was all my jinja. I didn't realize I could set variables in jinja. I took your exact loop and converted into jinja. Idk why I thought I needed that loop in my python code. To your point it fetches a data response from Watson and doesn't do anything with it.